# calling web method from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

here is the method i'm using in default.aspx.cs page

```
private void DeleteSelectedUser(object sender, DeleteItemRowClickedEventArgs e)
        { //logic goes here
}
```

calling above method in a jquery of default.asmx page, below is my jquery i used. I'm able to get popup but unable to fire method, help me

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function UserDel() {
        $("#message").html("Are you sure you want to delete User?");
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Delete Confirmation",
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Users.aspx/DeleteSelectedUser",
                        data: "{}",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            // Do something interesting here.
                        }
                    });
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    return false;
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: See http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: You are hitting on the `Users.aspx` in Your `url` not `default.asmx`

Comment: Have you added `[WebMethod]` attribute and the `ScriptManager` and `EnablePageMethods`?

Comment: @NaveedYousaf The web method is on the page instead of an ASMX, according to the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You need few things to run your method from jquery:

1. You are missing the WebMethod attribute on the function.
2. You are not passing data to the webmethod.

I suggest you change your method as follow :

```
[WebMethod]
private void DeleteSelectedUser()
{ 
  //logic goes here
}
```

Once you hit the method then pass your parameters in `data`.

Answer (score -1):

The best way by all means (in my humbled opinion) is using ASP Button set it's visibility to hidden by javascript and put it inside an update panel, and call it with JS after doing your logic, and let it call the backend functions for you.